# Converting Javascript date string to PHP date

Tags: php, date, datetime, laravel

I'm stuck trying to convert a string in a Javascript format into a format I can use in PHP for filtering.

An example of the date string that I'm given is
 "Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"

Let's say I have that assigned to a variable $z.  When I run the following, I get an unexpected result:

```
$z = "Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)";
$value = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($z));
```

This gives me $value = "1970-01-01 00:00:00", obviously not what I wanted.  I've also tried the following with no luck:

```
$value = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s',$z); //Fails
```

Now I'm pretty sure that the timezone info is what is messing everything up, but I just can't seem to figure out what to do here.  I'm using Laravel 5, so I've also attempted similar operations with Carbon. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code gives the error `Trailing data` (using `DateTime::getLastErrors()`). This is because your pattern doesn't take in consideration the timezone after the time ( `GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)` ) .

So you need to use the T operator to match the GMT-0800 part, and a generic + symbol to just igonre the rest. Your final pattern will be:

```
$value = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s T +',$z);
```

which gives

```
 DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => -08:00
)
```

Good luck !

Comment: Wahib:  Thanks for the help on this!  You know, I tried the format 'D M d Y H:i:s |' before because I thought the pipe symbol would do what the + did.  Apparently not. Your help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: @Wahib,Thanks man! I went as far as  DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e',$z); to create date from "Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800". Replaced e with your suggested T + and it worked like a glove for the full date with (Standard Time). Much appreciated!